# Combining for loop

Tags: c#

I am doing a program that has multiple buttons and textboxes. The program I am creating now is not even 50% complete but the code lines is over 5000 making the program too big. Is there a way to combine these for loop statements:

For the first textbox when it is clicked.

```
var btn = new[] { btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10, btn11, btn12, btn13, btn14 };
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    if (txt1.Text == btn[i].Text)
    {
        txt1.Text = "";
        btn[i].Visible = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

For the second textbox when it is clicked.

```
var btn = new[] { btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10, btn11, btn12, btn13, btn14 };
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
   if (txt2.Text == btn[i].Text)
   {
      txt2.Text = "";
      btn[i].Visible = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

and many more textbox.

Comment: use same click event for all the buttons.

Comment: Why not put this code in a function which takes in the `TextBox` you want to change? You could also use just the single event handler and then use the "sender" parameter to get a reference to the `TextBox`.

Comment: wire them all up to the same event and use the parameters to get the textbox out - or have all of them in their own events and call through to a shared method (passing in the text box)

Comment: Essentially your question could be reduced to _How do I avoid code clones/duplicate code as reported by tools such as VS or nDepend_.  There's bound to be plenty of stuff on the net for that.  At 3000 lines I suspect you have some other problems not listed in your question above

Comment: 5000 lines alone isn't a problem. The question is what these 5000 lines do. If they are mostly the same code repeated over and over again, then you can optimize the code. There are coding guidelines out there that can help you with that, but as a rule of thumb, if you do the same thing for multiple objects, you can use a method and only write the code once. Redundant code is something you should avoid as you have to change every occasion of that code if you made an error.

Comment: @MrUniverse please elaborate so I could understand by the use of a sample program.

Comment: @PlusUltra please consider my answer,i think its better than using loops. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a close look into the code that you are using, The thing which changing based on TextBox is the TextBox itself, so that you can accept it as an argument to the function and wrap the rest of statements inside the function. Then it will check the conditions and Change visibility of the button. which may look like the following:

```
 var arrayButtons = new Button[] { btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10, btn11, btn12, btn13, btn14 };
 // Let the array be Global so that we can avoid defining the same every call
 public void ChangeButtonVisibility(TextBox currentText)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < arrayButtons.Length; i++)
     {
         if (currentText.Text == arrayButtons[i].Text)
         {
             currentText.Text = "";
             arrayButtons[i].Visible = true;
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

So that you can call the method like this when TextBox1 Clicked:

```
ChangeButtonVisibility(TextBox1);
```

Like this for TextBox2 Clicked

```
ChangeButtonVisibility(TextBox2);
```

Comment: While you are at it, make the Button array a private static readonly field so it does not need to be reconstructed every time.

Comment: @MrUniverse : Thanks for the suggestion, i have edited it already.

Comment: Thanks @un-lucky. I was thinking of a different approach until I saw this. It help me shorten my code.

Comment: @PlusUltra : Happy to hear that i helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make another array with the text boxes and loop over both arrays:

```
var txts = new[] { txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6, txt7, txt8, txt9, txt10, txt11, txt12, txt13, txt14 };
var btns = new[] { btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10, btn11, btn12, btn13, btn14 };

foreach(var txt in txts)
{
    foreach(var btn in btns)
    {
        if (txt.Text == btn.Text)
        {
            txt.Text = "";
            btn.Visible = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you avoid writing all the specific click events and make one click event for all of your textboxes.
in order to do that you have to add a pointer to the tag of the textbox,which points to corresponding button. i would do that in the load event of the form like this :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Tag = btn1;
    textBox2.Tag = btn2;
    textBox3.Tag = btn3;
    textBox4.Tag = btn4;
    textBox5.Tag = btn5;
    textBox6.Tag = btn6;
}
```

now that you have the buttons as tags of your controls, all you gotta do is make a click event for all your textboxes, cast sender, and check the control versus its tag :

```
private void allTextboxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as TextBox).Text == ((sender as TextBox).Tag as Button).Text)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).Text = "";
        ((sender as TextBox).Tag as Button).Visible = true;
    }
}
```

i would strongly prefer this kind of code over loops.

Comment: I've taken your comment/answer into consideration but as a student I am only allowed to use codes that my professor taught that's why I have chosen @un-lucky 's code. Don't worry if my professor teach these to us I am willing to use this code. Thanks by the way for your help.